# Data is not in the correct state to have this differential backup applied to it

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I cannot restore my SQL Server database.

I am restoring full backup and latest diff backup, but when trying to restore diff backup (in the same file, its number is 62) I get an error:

> XX is not in the correct state to have this differential backup applied to it.

How to overcome this please?

Thank you!

Comment: Of course I am restoring with NONRECOVERY and with RECOVERY while restoring diff.

Comment: which db version you are using ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Answer (score 0):

Let's verify backup file Log Sequence Number and make sure it's the correct full and differential backup you're storing.

To check the Log Sequence Number.

`RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'BACKUP_FILE_FULL_PATH'`

The result set will show you the last LSN. to restore from a differential backup you need a full + last differential backup from the same backup set.

Comment: which columns I should check?

Comment: Here are the last LSN values

20328000000026800001
27930000000046200001
28255000000020500001
28361000000017600001
28471000000012500001
28619000000042500001
28758000000039400001
28912000000011100001
29086000000029100001
29251000000075500001
29448000000032000001
29632000000026400001
29840000000030000001
30155000000028800001
30349000000032100001
......
35344000000272200001
35436000000169600001
35519000000080300001

Comment: You have to examine the LSN of the full and diff backup file you're working on. Only if the LSNs are matching you can get a full + diff backup restored. Refer to https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3209/understanding-sql-server-log-sequence-numbers-for-backups/

Comment: FirstLSN of full backup and diff databasebackuplsn does not match, how can I overcome it

Comment: That means it's not the correct set of backups you're using.

Comment: But I am sure that I have taken a manual full backup and then automated it to differential. Any way to overcome this and get back the data?